# Как разместить тест в в mat-toolbar по центру

Tags: angular, angular-material

Пытаюсь разместить текст по центру в элементе mat-toolbar Angular Material. Но он все равно остается в левом углу. Пробовал использовать при выравнивании Bootstrap, все равно тест остается с лева.

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>
    <div class="my-header">
        Тест заголовка
    </div>
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

css файл

```html
.my-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать так:
Делаем блок `my-header`, который займет всю ширину и высоту в `mat-toolbar`. Он будет своеобразным контейнером, относительно него уже спозиционируем через flex наш контент, в данном случае это блок с текстом.

```css
.my-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="my-header">
    <div>Тест заголовка</div>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Пример можно посмотреть на [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-murrq3-h4xze9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-basic-example.html)

P.S. Использовать еще и bootstrap для того, чтобы задавать стили - это избыточно. Angular-Material и так содержит стили, по сути вы используете две крупные библиотеки со стилями, что не очень хорошо.